# A "natural homomorphism" $H^n(B; \Bbb Z) \rightarrow H^n(B; \Bbb Z_2)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

This is [Proposition 4.12, pg33](http://web.math.ku.dk/~moller/students/mauricio.pdf) The claim of the statement is:

> The natural homomorphism $\Gamma:H^n(B;\Bbb Z) \rightarrow H^n(B ; \Bbb Z_2)$ sends the Euler class to the top Stiefel Whitney class.

My confusion, is, what exactly is this natural homomorphism?

---

Is this given by taking a cochain $\varphi:C_n(B) \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ and post compose by quotient map - if so, is it clear this well defined?

Comment: You can always compose maps, can't you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a natural transformation $Hom(-,\mathbb Z) \to Hom(-,\mathbb Z/2)$ of endofunctors of abelian groups induced by the quotient map. Applying this to the chain complex $C_n(B;\mathbb Z)$ determines the morphism of cochain complexes $$C^n(B; \mathbb Z) \to C^n(B; \mathbb Z/2)$$
morphisms of complexes always induce morphisms on cohomology.